# Signups with ThinkTecture IdentityServer/STS/Claims-based auth

Tags: .net

I've been playing with the ThinkTecture IdentityServer recently, and I hooked up a simple project which to use the IdentityServer as an [STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Token_Service) for [claims-based, federated authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity).  So effectively, "login" works.  What I'm now trying to figure out is how to allow signups.

With the whole IdentityServer/STS/Claims-based model, how can I allow users to sign up?  I've looked around and found almost nothing on the topic.  This leads me to wonder: do I have to do signups using a separate service which writes to the same user store shared by the IdentityServer/STS?  Or is there some other solution?

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to the whole .NET Authentication/Authorization topic.